# ipad databinding

Tags: iphone, data-binding, ipad, user-controls

Is there a way to data bind some data to a view's controls in an ipad app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) it is currently not available on the iOS platform. You could perhaps look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151502/143) as a starting point.